# Finding the nth character in a list of text

Tags: python

```
    import re

    text = "~SR1*abcde*1234*~end~SR*abcdef*123*~end~SR11*abc*12345*~end"
```

I have a text that is repetitive in nature. It starts with '~SR' and ends with 'end'. i want to find the index of the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd ' * ' (asterisk) from each repetition.

```
    def start_point(p1):
        segment_start_array = []
        for match in re.finditer(p1, text):
            index = match.start()
            segment_start_array.append(index)
        return segment_start_array


    def point_a(p1):
        a = start_point(p1)
        return a


    def point_b(p2):
        b = start_point(p2)
        return b


    def get_var_section(p1, p2):
        var_list = []
        for each in range(len(start_point(p1))):
            list = text[point_a(p1)[each]:point_b(p2)[each]]
            var_list.append(list)
        return var_list


    print(get_var_section('~SR', '~end'))
```

==> Result: `['~SR1*finda*1234*', '~SR*Findab*123*', '~SR11*findabc*12345*']`

What i did first is put the repetitions into a list, which resulted into three elements. By doing this I thought it would make it easier to find the position of each asterisk, but when i tried to find the index of the 1st and 2nd asterisk the result were the same.

```
    def test(p1, p2, occurrence):
        var_list4 = []
        for i in get_var_section(p1, p2):
            x = i.find('*', occurrence)
            var_list4.append(x)
        return var_list4


    print(test('~SR', '~end', 1))
    print(test('~SR', '~end', 2))
```

==> Result: `[4, 3, 5]` 
==> Result: `[4, 3, 5]` 
I don't understand why the result didn't change after i changed to find the position of the 2nd occurrence.

Comment: The second parameter of `str.find` is the starting point of search (in **characters**) from beginning of string.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. So, it's n + occurrence. How would i reference the first result into the function to get the second position? i tried n + occurrence, but of course it didnt work because i can't call the x variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned that the string starts and ends with *(~SR1, ~end)*, I split the string with `~end` and then used `item` to loop through the list to find indexes in the `item`.

```
import re

text = "~SR1*abcde*1234*~end~SR*abcdef*123*~end~SR11*abc*12345*~end"
text_list = text.split('~end')
index = []
for item in text_list:
    #print(item)
    if len(item) > 0:
        ind = [i for i, val in enumerate(item) if val == '*']
        #print(ind)
        index.append(ind)
index_new = np.array(index).T.tolist() #transpose of list of lists
```

Result

```
print("index") 

[[4, 10, 15], [3, 10, 14], [5, 9, 15]]

print("index_new") 

[[4, 3, 5], [10, 10, 9], [15, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: No worries, happy to help

Comment: follow up question. What if i want the result to be `[4, 3, 5], [10, 10, 9], [15, 14, 15]`. Basically, grouping the first occurrences together, the second occurrences together and so forth?

Comment: Will the number of * change in each split sentence?  
Currently in this text 
```text = "~SR1*abcde*1234*~end~SR*abcdef*123*~end~SR11*abc*12345*~end"``` we have exactly three * inbetween each ~SR1 and ~end. 
Do you get any sequence in the following way 
```text ="~SR1*abc*de*1234*~end~SR*ab*cd*ef*123*~end~SR11*abc*12*345*~end"```

Comment: The number of * is the same in each split sentence. The only thing that is not constant are the number of characters in between the *.

Comment: Added the new updated code above, please check it. I have just done a transpose of the output which we got earlier

Comment: i see that you used `np.array()`. It looks like a Numpy array, which I've seen on a similar post somewhere. For some reason i was getting an error message when i tried to install Numpy. Thank you. I will try the figure out how to install Numpy and try the new code.

Comment: If you have issue with numpy, you can loop through each inner list extract items separately. That would take 4-5 lines of codes, but using numpy/ transpose is efficient and recommendable.